# prevent method from executing from different threads at the same time

Tags: c#

Am I correct that the only way to prevent a method from being executed twice at the same time is by using a `lock` statement?

```
private object lockMethod = new object();

public void Method() {
    lock (lockMethod) {
        // work
    }
}

public void FromThread1() {
    Method();
}

public void FromThread2() {
    Method();
}
```

Of course I can also use `MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)` what would be almost the same.

Are there other techniques?

Comment: I'm a little worried that you're trying to lock a _method_ rather than locking _data_ -- what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Since you don't show any `static` methods, are you really trying to prevent executing a method twice for the same instance at the same time?  Or any two methods for a single instance at the same time?

Comment: the method is so small that in my situation locking the method = locking the data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Am I correct that the only method to prevent method to execute twice at the same time is using lock statement?

No, but this is the "standard" way, and probably the best.  That being said, typically you'd use a lock to synchronize access to *specific data*, not to a method as a whole.  Locking an entire method will likely cause more blocking than necessary.

As for other methods, the [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading) namespace contains many other types used for synchronization in various forms, including `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, `Semaphore`, `Mutex`, the `Monitor class` (which is what `lock` uses internally), etc.  All provide various ways to synchronize data, though each is geared for a different scenario.  In this case, `lock` is the appropriate method to use.